# How is it possible to reposition a jQuery Mobile dialog page after adding content dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

How is it possible to reposition a jQuery Mobile dialog page after adding content dynamically? I need it to be back in the center of the screen again.
Thnx!

Edit: The content added is upsizing the dialog window to the bottom.

Comment: Add your content on the `pagebeforeshow` event. Also you should create a jsfiddle so people can better help you.

Comment: in this case this doesn't work because I need some width-data from elements within the dialog page, so the page needs to be completly build. you are right that jsfiddle is fantastic to use but as long as I can describe the problem with a few words there is no need to set up external links that may be gone in a few years...

Comment: Could you indicate what type of content you have added and how it impacted the positioning ?

Comment: prepare an example so others can help you. Thank you.

Comment: I will try to reproduce this as JSBIN when I find the time. thnx!
downraters, please go back to classic forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that you need to use .ui-dialog-contain to grab the dialog window. Than simple jQuery is enough...

```
function reCenter() {
    $('#box').find('.ui-dialog-contain').css("position","absolute");
    $('#box').find('.ui-dialog-contain').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height()/2 - $('#box').find('.ui-dialog-contain').outerHeight()) / 2)) + "px");
    $('#box').find('.ui-dialog-contain').css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $('#box').find('.ui-dialog-contain').outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
}
```